# Use local variable inside included code in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, require

I am trying to use local variable inside the included code but getting an error.

app.js:

```
import RequireDir from "require-dir";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";

...

client.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const id = socket.id;

    RequireDir("./data", { recurse: true, noCache: true });
}
```

data/main.js:

```
console.log(id);
```

It will show this error on Runtime:
`ReferenceError: id is not defined`

There is any solution?

Comment: In the snippet in your post, there is no reference to `user`. Where are you trying to use this variable?

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access variables that are initialized inside a function outside of that function.

The question is what you are trying to do with that socket ID. This socket ID is unique for each session, and you should not expose that to global variables.
The best approach would be to write a function that takes that ID and handles it.

data/main.js:

```
export const handleSocket = (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  // ... rest of your code
};
```

app.js:

```
import RequireDir from "require-dir";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import { handleSocket } from "data/main.js"; // import the function

...

client.on("connection", (socket) => {

  // pass socket to your handler
  handleSocket(socket);

  RequireDir("./data", { recurse: true, noCache: true });
}
```

You might want to [read about javascript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to understand scoping of variables.

Comment: This doesn't help me, because I have 100 files in the data directory that use the `id` variable. That's why I use `RequireDir` - I need it dynamic.

Comment: then please adjust your question and state what you are doing and what your limitations are.

Comment: I explained the issue. I am trying to dynamically include files and use a local variable inside them. Thank you!

Comment: still, you should improve your question and write that you want to pass the ID to 100 files. your question currently suggests that you only have one file where you need it. You did also not mention that it has to work dynamically on all files in the directory. It would also help if you post a full example of one those files from `./data` directory where the `id` is used, so it is easier to understand what you are trying to accomplish